# Открыть ссылку не в приложение PWA а в браузере?

Tags: javascript, app, pwa

При разработке своего приложения PWA столкнулся с такой проблемой что все ссылки открываются через это приложения на смартфоне. Ситуация такая мое приложение лежит по адресу https://site.test/app/
и все движения приложения происходят в этой папки /app/.
Например мне на воцап скидывают ссылку https://site.test/help.html - надо что бы она открылась в браузере но все ссылки проекта открываются в приложении PWA.
Погуглил, советуют в manifest.json прописать строчку "capture_links": "none", это не помогло, так же был совет прикрутить модуль https://github.com/WICG/web-app-launch но тоже не помогло.
Прошу поделиться какими то советами или реальном опытом в решении данной проблемы.